# Adding elements on loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to generate a row of 16 boxes on load of webpage.

Here is my code:

```
var box = $("<div></div>").addClass("box");
    $(document).ready(function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
                $("#container").append(box);
                }
            });
```

I also tried this within the for loop's code block:

```
if($("#container:contains(box)")) {
   $(box).append(box);
}
```

I kind of understand why this does not work.  That `var box` is only referencing an element and is not a copy of an element?

As you can likely tell, I'm new.  I would really appreciate some pointers on how I can achieve this.  Thanks.

Comment: `$("#container").append(box.clone());` would work. More efficient doing this as string though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending the *same* div over and over. That will just move it (in this case, right back where it was).  For a new `div` each time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var ctr = $('#container');

  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    ctr.append("<div class='box'></div>");
  }
});
```

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var ctr = $('#container');

    for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      ctr.append("<div class='box'></div>");
    }
  });
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Seems so simple now that you have shown me how, ha!  Thank you Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use like this?

```
for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
   $("#container").append('<div class="box box-'+i+'" />');
}
```

Comment: That will leave strange attributes: `<div class="box box-"0 />`, etc. You probably meant `$("#container").append('<div class="box box-' + i + '" />');

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against using `append` in a loop, [bad performance](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly). I suggest this:

```
  var buffer = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    buffer.push("<div class='box'></div>");
  }

  var html=buffer.join('');
  $('#container').append(html);
```

Comment: I'll have a play about with this method also.  Thanks.